# Perplexed over a simple function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function

Look at the code below:

```
def foo (x):

    print("foo environment: x = {0}".format(x))
    def bar (z, x = 0):
        print("bar environment: z = {0} and x = {1}.  Value to be returned: {2}".format(z, x, x+z))
        return z + x

    return bar(3)

foo(5)

foo environment: x = 5
bar environment: z = 3 and x = 0.  Value to be returned: 3
3
```

Since in the foo environment x = 5, why bar uses the value 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only passing one argument here:

```
return bar(3)
```

The bar function accepts two values, one `z` and one `x` (x has a default value (0) and that is why only 1 argument is enough). By only passing the `z`, x=0.

Try this, and see what happens:

```
return bar(3, x)
```